# iOS Memory Leak cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uitableview

The leak instrument points to "cell.textLabel.text = str;" as a memory leak. I am not sure why since I autoreleased the cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

// Try to retrieve from the table view a now-unused cell with the given identifier.
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

// If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier.
if (cell == nil) {
    // Use the default cell style.
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Set up the cell.
NSString *str = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = str;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: What if you try using `NSString *str = [NSString stringWithString:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might not have released the array object that you use for getting the Strings.Also , try casting the value after extracting from array as

```
   str= [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@",(NSString *)[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```